# Store Click Coordinates Using Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, click

I am trying to display an image, click on it somewhere, then store those coordinates into a variable. However, I am unable to do so. I can print the click coordinates no problem, but I cannot figure out a way to actually store those coordinates. The matplotlib documentation has some tutorials on how to use "fig.canvas.mpl_connect" in general, but none of the routines cover storing the click coordinates, which is what I want to do. There are some tutorials on StackExchange, as well as other websites, but they seem to be for outdated versions of python and/or matplotlib.

Here is my simple code right now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 0

def onclick(event):
    print(event.xdata)
    print(event.ydata)
    global x
    x = event.xdata

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

plt.show()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

print(x)
```

Upon running this code, it immediately prints '0', THEN displays the image. When I then click on that figure, I get coordinates printed to the console. I have tried putting a pause command before the print statement, but it just waits to print '0', then displays the image. Essentially, I need it to display the image so I can click it, THEN print the coordinates of my click.

Any help would be appreciated. I am also open to another method of obtaining the click coordinates, if one exists. Thank you.

Comment: put `print(x)` ***into*** the onclick callback.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstand what I'm trying to do. I can get it to print the coordinates no problem. The print statements inside the "onclick" function do the job no problem. The issue is that I can't store these coordinates for later use. The last print statement should, in my mind, print the x coordinate, but it doesn't. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not sure. That print statement is executed before you even click anywhere, so it cannot know what happens in the future. That's why anything you want to do that requires the user to click needs to be inside the callback.

Comment: So how can I get the click coordinates and store them into a variable to be used outside the click callback?

Comment: You can make any variable `global` to use it outside a function. But that's besides the point; because that variable would not hold the coordinates, *until* you click somewhere.